# macOS Catalina : Dock automatically getting selected instead of other opened windows

Tags: catalina, dock, window-manager

I am new to Mac. I have both Safari and Xcode window open. Problem is, whenever I am quiting my Xcode, currently open Safari window isn't automatically getting selected. Instead Dock getting selected. Every time I'm quiting an application I have to click on top visible window for focus and start work.

How can I change this behaviour to have the next application selected instead?

Comment: *Doc getting selected*?   It’s not clear what you’re referring to here.  A *document*?   What document is being selected over an open Safari window?

Comment: Hi @Allan: Sorry for misspelling `Dock`. I was referring to https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/dock/info. Thanks! @nohillside for edit.